# Nodemon not installed after docker build image

Tags: node.js, docker, nodemon

I have an image for a node app. In the package.json I have nodemon. I want to run the container with updates to the host source, where `nodemon` will hot reload with changes in host src. So I am using a bind mount.

`package.json` from node app.

```
{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon app.js"
  },
  "author": "MOI",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.10.3",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0"
  },
 "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4"
 }
}
```

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM node

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json .

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Then I run the container with this, I can't see that `nodemon` is operation, when I check the logs. Almost like it didn't install at all. Any ideas how I can troubleshoot this?

```
docker run --name goals-backend -v /Users/path/for/bind/mount/backend:/app \
-v logs:/app/logs -v /app/node_modules -d --rm \
-p 80:80 --network goals-net goals-node
```

Comment: If your goal is to have live reloading on host code, would it make more sense to use a host-based Node environment, rather than introducing Docker as an isolation layer and then trying to work around its isolation features?

Comment: Fair point. I am working through a tutorial, so I might never try to accomplish this in real life.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bind on /app 'hides' all the content in '/app' in the image and replaces it with the content of /Users/path/for/bind/mount/backend on the host machine.
The same with the volume on /app/node_modules although since that's a volume and not a bind mount, the content of /app/node_modules will be copied to the volume when the volume is first created.

Run it without volume mappings to make sure that the image works as-is

```
docker run --name goals-backend -d --rm -p 80:80 --network goals-net goals-node
```

Comment: Hi! I did try everything again, with the first run command without the volumes as you stated, but still nothing. I see no indication that `nodemon` is installed or the `npm start` script is running.

Comment: After deleting my volumes, this is now working.